# How large or small can the gap in Shelah's main gap theorem be, up to consistency?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Shelah's main gap theorem in model theory says:

> For each first order complete theory $T$ in a countable language if $I(T,\kappa)$ denotes the number of its models of size $\kappa$ then one of these situations holds:
>
> **(a)** $\forall \alpha>0~~~~~I(T,\aleph_\alpha)=2^{\aleph_\alpha}$
>
> **(b)** $\forall \alpha>0~~~~~I(T,\aleph_\alpha)<\beth_{\omega_{1}}(|\alpha|)$

Now consider the open interval $(\beth_{\omega_{1}}(|\alpha|),2^{\aleph_\alpha})$ for each given positive ordinal $\alpha$. I would like to know how large or small can this gap be, up to consistency? In the other words, what is the "diameter" of the "gap-zone" $(\beth_{\omega_{1}}(|\alpha|),2^{\aleph_\alpha})$ in Shelah's theorem and how this diameter does change by increasing cardinals? Precisely:

**Question:** Let $F:Ord\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow Card$ be as follows:
$$\forall\alpha>0~~~~~F(\alpha):=|(\beth_{\omega_{1}}(|\alpha|),2^{\aleph_\alpha})\cap Card|$$

**(a)** What is the minimum definable cardinal $\lambda$ such that:

$$Con(ZFC+~\text{Possibly some extra assumptions}~)\Longrightarrow Con(ZFC+\forall\alpha\in Ord^{>0}~~~~~F(\alpha)\leq \lambda)$$

(Assuming GCH we can choose $\lambda=0$)

**(b)** For which definable cardinal $\lambda$ we have:

$$Con(ZFC+~\text{Possibly some extra assumptions}~)\Longrightarrow Con(ZFC+\forall\alpha\in Ord^{>0}~~~~~F(\alpha)\geq \lambda)$$

How large can such a cardinal be?

**Remark:** Any other criterion for measuring the largeness of the gap zone $(\beth_{\omega_{1}}(|\alpha|),2^{\aleph_\alpha})$ is welcome. I think the exponential nature of the lower bound in Shelah's theorem adds some limitations on the largeness of this gap.

**Motivation:** It is possible to prove theorems which give us different amount of information up to consistency, depends on the various situations of the parameters in a particular model of ZFC with special properties. For example in Shelah's main gap theorem the quantity $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ has no determined value by alephs and this can change the largeness of the gap which Shelah's theorem describes.

Comment: Gaps are usually measured in order type, not cardinality. Otherwise, how can you differ a gap of $\omega$ and a gap of $\omega^3+1$?

Comment: *Gap*, not gape.

Comment: Just as a remark, in question 2 necessarily $\lambda=0$, since your interval is empty whenever $\alpha$ is an $\aleph$-fixed point.